# UIScrollView contentInset vs simply increase contentSize

Tags: ios, objective-c

In a UIScrollView, the alternative to use contentInset is to simply make the contentSize larger and offset the frames of the subviews of the UIScrollView. As far as I know, these two approaches yield identical result. Is that the correct understanding? What are the pros and cons of each approach?

Answer (score -1):

Using `contentSize` to achieve an inset effect creates more work for you, and it does not make the scrollView aware that you are trying to achieve an inset.

When presenting a view controller in iOS7 the OS may want to mess with your insets, per the `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` property added to `UIViewController` in iOS7. If you aren't using the `contentInsets` property, it won't be able to take your existing insets into account when the scrollView gets presented. This will probably cause your view to look misaligned.

Use `contentInset` if you can, that is precisely the reason they give you access to that property.

Comment: What does it mean when you said "it does not make scrollView aware that you are trying to achieve with an inset"?

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain a little more clearly. If you don't set the contentInset property of the scrollView, it doesn't realize that you're actually trying to achieve an inset.

Comment: You still did not address the question. What exactly is the visual difference between using contentInset and contentSize?

Comment: There is no visual difference between the two approaches except in the cases I described in my answer. You are just misusing the API.